# Laravel patch method just refreshes page, doesn't update database fields

Tags: laravel

Controller function:

```
    public function setFlag(Request $request)
{
    $user = User::find((int)$request->input('id'));
    $user->flag = 1;
    $user->save();
}
```

Blade file

```
@extends ('layouts.app')
@section('content')
@if($user->user_picture)
    <img src= "data:{{$user->user_picture_type}};base64,{{$user->user_picture}}" height="100" width="100">
@else
    <img src="{{ URL::to('/') }}/images/blankProfile.png" height="100" width="100">
@endif
<div>Name: {{$user->name}}</div>
<div>Bio: {{$user->bio}}</div>
<div>Child Bio: {{$user->child_bio}}</div>
<div>Parent Age: {{$user->parent_age}}</div>
<div>Child Age: {{$user->child_age}}</div>
<div>City: {{$user->city}}</div>
<div>State: {{$user->state}}</div>
<a href="/ratings/{{$user->id}}"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">View Users Ratings</button></a>
<br />
<br />
  {{Form::open(array('action' => array('ProfileController@setFlag', $user->id), 'method' => 'PATCH'))}}
 {{ csrf_field() }}
 <input type="hidden" value = "{{$user->id}}" id = "id" name = "id">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Report User</button>
{{Form::close()}}
@if(Auth::user()->level == 1)
    <br />
    <br />
    <a href="/"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Delete User</button></a>
    @if($user->flag == 1)
    <a href="/"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Unflag</button></a>
    @endif
@endif  
@endsection
```

All routes for the profile controller:

```
Route::get('/profile', 'ProfileController@index')->middleware('auth')->name('profile.index');
Route::get('/profile/edit', 'ProfileController@edit')->middleware('auth');
Route::resource('profile', 'ProfileController')->middleware('auth');
Route::get('/profile/{userID}', 'ProfileController@show')->middleware('auth');
Route::patch('/profile/{userID}','ProfileController@setFlag')->middleware('auth');
```

So my issue is when the user clicks the submit button, it just refreshes the page and does nothing inside of the controller. I had a dd($request) inside of the controller, and it never even hit the dd. I've spent a few hours trying out different solutions, and nothing so far has worked. I've tried changing the route name, using a default html form, using the laravel form differently, messing with the controller, and attempting to force the flag to be set for a specific user on the button press, but none of those worked.

I'm thinking the issue has to do with the route....But I have no idea how to route a patch method that isn't included inside the default Route::resource. Is it because there are two different routes for /profile/{userID}? Any help is appreciated, and thank you for your time

Edit: Update function inside of profilecontroller

```
 public function update($id, Request $request)
    {                
        $user = User::find(Auth::user()->getId());          

        $request->validate([
                'name' => 'required',
                'image' => '|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,svg|max:2048',
                'bio' => 'required',
                'child_bio' => 'required',
                'parent_age' => 'required|integer|min:18',
                'city' => 'required',
                'state' => 'required',
                'child_age' => 'required|integer|between:1,8',

        ]);
        if($request->hasFile('image')) {
            $user_picture = base64_encode(file_get_contents($request->file('image')));
            $user_picture_type = $_FILES['image']['type'];

            DB::table('users')->where('id', $id)->update(
                [
                    'user_picture' => $user_picture,
                    'user_picture_type' => $user_picture_type
                ]
            );
        }


        $name = $request->input('name');
        $bio = $request->input('bio');
        $child_bio = $request->input('child_bio');
        $parent_age = $request->input('parent_age');
        $city = $request->input('city');
        $state = $request->input('state');
        $child_age = $request->input('child_age');
        $geocoder = new \OpenCage\Geocoder\Geocoder('8c0bbd03698f4bdaa4e35fe38c30fbd1');
        $result = $geocoder->geocode($city . ' ' . $state);
        $first = $result['results'][0];
        $lat = $first['geometry']['lat'];
        $lng = $first['geometry']['lng'];
        //$level = 1;        


        DB::table('users')->where('id', $id)->update(
            [
                'name' => $name,
                'bio' => $bio,
                'child_bio' => $child_bio,
                'parent_age' => $parent_age,
                'city' => $city,
                'state' => $state,
                'child_age' => $child_age,
                'lat' => $lat,
                'lng' => $lng,

            ]
        ); 
       return redirect('/profile');

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

first you can check what type of data you receive

```
    public function setFlag(Request $request)
{
    dd($request);
    //$user = User::find((int)$request->input('id'));
    //$user->flag = 1;
    //$user->save();
}
```

if everything is ok then you can check User model after that you can find same id and update what you want

Comment: protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'verified', 'password', 'bio', 'child_age', 'city', 'state', 'child_bio', 
        'parent_age', 'user_picture', 'user_picture_type', 'gender', 'flag',
    ]; I have that inside my user model. I tried throwing in a dd($request) but it was never being hit in the controller. That's why I'm really confused. It's not even hitting the controller.

Comment: that means problem is here it's not reach the controller. so first of all we are fixing this

Comment: I'm showing you can use resources and you can again use patch.
but why??
if you can use resources then it's work for all

Comment: go to your ProfileController and find the update method and do dd($request) on this

Comment: That's what I thought the issue was. I am using patch because it's updating 1 field in the database to a fixed number. Should I do this inside of public function update()? That already has a lot of code in it. That is why I made a new function called setFlag since update was already being used.

Comment: but you need to findout your view form where he go??
check this file i think your view form redirect from there

Comment: I added my update function to the post. There is already a lot of code in there, so I wasn't sure if I could still use that function or not.

Comment: so you change your route 
Route::patch('/profile/user/{userID}','function(){ return "work"}')->middleware('auth');
go to your browser and type url/user/1